# React Native POST request with Axios: Network Error even after using Server's IP

Tags: android, react-native

I have my local REST API served in `http://localhost:4000` however, any axios request from React Native is not working, it always yields to `Network Error` but requests works fine in `Postman`.
I am running the app on my `physical android device` through a cable.

I've tried using the IP address of the server's machine being run which I got by running `ipconfig` on command line but still no luck

```
// const APIUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/api/v1';
const APIUrl = 'http://192.168.12.4:4000/api/v1';

export const axiosClient = axios.create({ baseURL: APIUrl });

export const login = async (username, password) => {
   try {
     const res = await axiosClient({ 
        url: '/login',
        method: 'POST',
        data: { username, password },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } 
     });

     return res.data;
   } catch (err) {
     console.log(err);
   }
}
```

I execute the app by running these commands

```
$ adb -s <mydevice> reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

$ npx react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what has caused the problem. I didn't know that the emulator was connected to other wifi network, they should be on the same network.